# error for ionic2 importing D3

Tags: d3.js, typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm implementing an app by using ionic2 and I need to draw some graphs. 
So, I decided to use d3.js. However, I'm getting an error during importing d3 in project.

I tried below:

```
$npm install d3 --save

$typings install d3 --save
```

in app.ts,

```
import * as d3 from 'd3' 
           or
import * as d3 from '../../node_modules/d3/d3' 
           or
import * as d3 from '../../typings/modules/d3'
```

then, I got an error like this :

> "TypeScript error: app/app.ts(6,21): Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'd3'"

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you using angular-cli for your project ?Besides Angular-beneficiary,  It has some great advantages for importing 3rd party libraries

Comment: @pdfarhad sorry for late reply. it work! thank you.